# Visual Explanation Guidance needed for reversal of Linked List datastructure code?

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, linked-list

I have following piece of code for reversing the linked list. I am getting confused in while loop and so would certainly appreciate if someone can provide visual explanation of how actually it's working.

```
 static void Reverse (struct node** headRef)
{
     struct node* result = NULL;
     struct node* current = *headref;
     struct node* next;

     while(current != NULL)
     {
        next = current->next;
        current->next = result;
        result = current;

        current = next;
     }     
     *headRef = result;

}
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

OK, here's my attempt to make valya's answer even clearer (though I thought it was pretty good already):

Say we have this list:

```
// a->b->c->d->e->NULL
```

We start at the first node, `a`, which contains a pointer (`next`) to `b`:

```
// a->b ...
```

The line `next = current->next;` sets `next` to `b` (simple enough). The next line `current->next = result;` does this:

```
// NULL<-a  b ... (notice there is no longer a pointer from a to b)
```

Then we have `result = current;` which sets `result` to `a` (again, simple enough). And finally, we have the all important `current = next;`, which set `current` to `b`.

So on the next iteration of the while loop, with `next` set to `b`, `result` set to `a`, and `current` set to `b`, we start over:

```
next = current->next;

// NULL<-a<-b  c ...
current->next = result;

result = current;
```

Then we do it again:

```
next = current->next;

// NULL<-a<-b<-c  d ...
current->next = result;

result = current;
```

Once we've gotten to the last item in the linked list (`e` in this example), this happens:

```
next = current->next; // next becomes NULL

// NULL<-a<-b<-c<-d<-e
current->next = result;

result = current; // result is now e

current = next; // current is now NULL
```

*Now*, since `current` is NULL, the while loop terminates, and we are left with:

```
*headRef = result;
```

which, as you can see now, makes `headRef` point to `e`, treating `e` as the new first item in our linked list, with `e->next` pointing to `d`, `d->next` pointing to `c`, etc.

Answer (score 4):

I made a diagram in dot that I think will graphically explain what's going on:

[image: thumbnail]

[Link to full-sized image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XFLIm.png)

And here's the (sloppy) dot source in case anyone cares:

```
digraph g {
    label = "Start"
    subgraph cluster_1
    {
        a1 -> b1 -> c1;
        current1 -> a1;
        result1
        a1 [label="a"]
        b1 [label="b"]
        c1 [label="c"]
        current1 [label="current"]
        result1 [label="result"]
    }
    label = "Once through loop"
    subgraph cluster_2
    {
        current2 -> b2;
        result2 -> a2;
        b2 -> c2;
        a2 [label="a"]
        b2 [label="b"]
        c2 [label="c"]
        current2 [label="current"]
        result2 [label="result"]
    }
    label = "Twice through loop"
    subgraph cluster_3
    {
        current3 -> c3;
        result3 -> b3;
        b3 -> a3;
        a3 [label="a"]
        b3 [label="b"]
        c3 [label="c"]
        current3 [label="current"]
        result3 [label="result"]
    }
    label = "Final"
    subgraph cluster_4
    {
        result4 -> c4 -> b4 -> a4;
        a4 [label="a"]
        b4 [label="b"]
        c4 [label="c"]
        current4 [label="current"]
        result4 [label="result"]
    }
    label = ""

}
```

Comment: This is much more helpful. No wonder they say a picture is worth a thousand words

Answer (score 2):

Check out [this](http://www.openasthra.com/c-tidbits/reverse-linked-list-using-3-ptrs/) site for a visual representation.
There looks like a good codeproject explanation [here](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/recipes/ReverseLinkedList.aspx) too (See technique 3).

Comment: your first link is broken

Answer (score 1):

list looked like:

```
=>(1) => => => => => => => => =>(10)
```

we reversed every piece of the list

```
<=(1) => => => => => => => => =>(10)
<=(1) <= => => => => => => => =>(10)
<=(1) <= <= => => => => => => =>(10)
...
<=(1) <= <= <= <= <= <= <= <= <=(10)
```

so, now start is in the end, and we can look at the list from the different point and see:

```
=>(10) => => => => => => => => =>(1)
```

Comment: Can you provide diagrammatic explanation how actually things are happening at each step ?

Comment: check the link in the other comment: http://www.openasthra.com/c-tidbits/reverse-linked-list-using-3-ptrs/

Comment: Yes, my answer gives a visual representation

Answer (score -2):

See [here](http://techcraving.wordpress.com/2014/08/03/reversing-a-singly-linked-list/) for a good explanation. Here is the excerpt:

```
public class List {
    private class Node {
        int data;
        Node next;
    }
   private Node head;

   public void reverse() {
      if (head == null) return;
      Node prev = null,curr = head,next = null;
      while (curr != null) {
         next = curr.next;
         curr.next = prev;
         prev = curr;
         curr = next;
      }
      head = prev;
   }
}

The list:
==========
1->2->3->4->5
------------------------------------------------------------------
Running of the code:
============================
At start:
**********
head = 1;
prev = null,curr = 1, next = null
1st iteration of while loop:
******************************
next = 2;
2->3->4->5
curr.next = null;
1->null
prev = 1;
1->null
curr = 2;
2->3->4->5
2nd iteration of while loop:
******************************
next = 3
3->4->5
curr.next = 1
2->1->null
prev = 2
2->1->null
curr = 3
3->4->5
3rd iteration of while loop:
******************************
next = 4
4->5
curr.next = 2
3->2->1->null
prev = 3
3->2->1->null
curr = 4
4->5
4th iteration of while loop:
******************************
next = 5
5->null
curr.next = 3
4->3->2->1->null
prev = 4
4->3->2->1->null
curr = 5
5->null
5th iteration of while loop:
******************************
next = null
null
curr.next = 4
5->4->3->2->1->null
prev = 5
5->4->3->2->1->null
curr = null
There is no 6th iteration and the while loop terminates since 
curr is null and the check is for curr != null.
last statement: 
==================
head = prev
This statement leaves the list reversed with referencing head with the reversed node prev 
to become the new head node.
```