# Linked List reverse Function in java

Tags: java, data-structures, linked-list, reverse

I am new to programming, so can anyone explain me how the below code works?

```
Node reverse(Node node) {
    Node prev = null;
    Node current = node;
    Node next = null;

    while (current != null) {
        next = current.next;
        current.next = prev;

        prev = current;
        current = next;
    }

    node = prev;
    return node;
}
```

I just want to know exactly what is happening in the while loop.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Visual Explanation Guidance needed for reversal of Linked List datastructure code?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1482189/visual-explanation-guidance-needed-for-reversal-of-linked-list-datastructure-cod)

Comment: Shouldn't it be asked on codereview?

Comment: @TamasHegedus explaining how code works is off-topic on Code Review. See the [on-topic page](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) there.

Answer (score 1):

Basically it tries to reverse a *linked list* and as you probably know, every `Node` has two pointers: a `next` and a `prev`. In order to reverse the linked list, we should change these pointers in a way that you can see in the below picture(we want to change blue chain to red chain)

[image]

So for example imagine `Node 3` in the picture, what its `prev` field has been pointing to (`Node 2`) is going to be the next node of `Node 3` (in our desired red chain), so `current.next = prev;`(line 2) makes sense. But because we want to get to `Node 4` in the next iteration of the loop, before that we write `next = current.next;`(line 1) to save the next pointer of `Node 3` which **currently** points to `Node 4`, and finally at the end of each iteration we put back that with `current = next;`(line 4) to iterate to the next `Node`.
In the next iteration we need to do the same thing so now `prev` should point to `Node 3` and that's why we had `prev = current;`(line 3) to prepare `prev`.

[Picture reference](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/27742/How-To-Reverse-a-Linked-List-Different-Ways)

Answer (score 0):

For each node in the list it is changing the next pointer to point to the previous node.

eg. It is taking this linked list:

a->b->c

and changing it into:

a<-b<-c

Comment: Please give a reason for the downvote or provide a better answer yourself

Comment: The author most likely knows *what* the function does, but they don't know *how* it works.